# Ansible stdout - print a file content without any additional character

Tags: ansible, stdout, display

Running an Ansible playbook, is there a solution to print a file content without any extra character? Like a simple cat on Linux.

There is simple text file:

```
  cat /tmp/report-2023-10-19.html.txt
   server1 : The D:\ drive size is WRONG! Expected drive size: '1009'. Current size is: 100
   server2 : The D:\ drive size is WRONG! Expected drive size: '1009'. Current size is: 100
   server3 : The C:\ drive size is WRONG! Expected drive size: '12899'. Current size is: 126.51
   server4 : The C:\ drive size is WRONG! Expected drive size: '12899'. Current size is: 126.51
```

I would like to display the file content with Ansible:

```
- name: Display all findings
  debug:
   var: "file_content"
  vars:
   file_content: "{{ lookup('file', '/tmp/{{ reportfile }}.txt').splitlines() }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
  run_once: true
  when: num_lines.stdout | int > 0
  tags: always
```

Result:

```
  ok: [vmstfsh1 -> localhost] => {
      "file_content": [
          " server1 : The D:\\ drive size is WRONG! Expected drive size: '1009'. Current size is: 100 ",
          "",
          " server2 : The D:\\ drive size is WRONG! Expected drive size: '1009'. Current size is: 100 ",
          "",
          " server3 : The C:\\ drive size is WRONG! Expected drive size: '12899'. Current size is: 126.51 ",
          "",
          " server4 : The C:\\ drive size is WRONG! Expected drive size: '12899'. Current size is: 126.51"
      ]
  }
```

Is there a solution to print the file content without any extra character (",)? Like a simple cat on Linux.
I have found the ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK variable but I only can change the format using this option (yam, or json).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The play below

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: file_content
      vars:
        file_content: "{{ lookup('file', '/tmp/report-2023-10-19.html.txt') }}"
      when: file_content.splitlines()|length > 0
      run_once: true
```

will display what you want

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=yaml ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  file_content: |-
    server1 : The D:\ drive size is WRONG! Expected drive size: '1009'. Current size is: 100
    server2 : The D:\ drive size is WRONG! Expected drive size: '1009'. Current size is: 100
    server3 : The C:\ drive size is WRONG! Expected drive size: '12899'. Current size is: 126.51
    server4 : The C:\ drive size is WRONG! Expected drive size: '12899'. Current size is: 126.51

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************
test_11: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

You don't have to `delegate_to: localhost`. The lookup plugins always run on the controller.